# How to check if an image was blocked by a browser extension?

Tags: javascript, instagram

Following Scenario

- I'm using an Instagram Widgets, which shows the latest images of my Instagram Account
- Some users may use the [Facebook Container Add-On for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/facebook-container/)
- When using this extension, I get in my Dev Console: https://scontent-frt3-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.29350-15/289266284_164217016088926_3628290502802444200_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106.... Blocked By Extension - which is of course correct

How can I check if the images were blocked by an extension, so I can show the user fallback images?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can use the `onerror` attribute in your `<img>` tag to run code if there's an error loading the main image.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your quick answer. Sorry, I didn't add this: I already tried just that, but the problem is that the <img> is inside an iFrame, so I can't select it, right? 

I took a random image from instagram to check if it can be loaded, but unfortunately the instagram URL hash changes after a while, so that didn't work

Comment: If it's in an iframe in another domain, there's nothing you can do in your application.

Comment: @Barmar Alright. But thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the Facebook Container. I contacted the Instagram Widget Support and they were so kind to provide a solution:

```
const button = document.createElement('button');
button.classList.add('FacebookConnectButton');
button.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(button);
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationList) => {
    if(button.classList.contains('fbc-has-badge')){
        // hide the iframe or show the instructions how to add exception to facebook container
    }
});
observer.observe(button, {attributes: true});
```

Works in my case!